# Github file not rendering because of security error?

Tags: javascript, github

I am trying to access this particular link in my github repository:
https://github.com/hargun3045/readme/blob/master/pandas.md

It used to render well before, but now it's showing a blank screen like this one.

[image]

On looking at some other suggestions, I checked the developer tools and saw the below error:

[image]

**NOTE**: Issues in Chrome browser only, the render is perfectly fine in Firefox.

I want to debug the issue because I use chrome for most tasks.

Comment: I have no problem in viewing it right now (Chrome/Ubuntu).

Comment: you think it would be caused due to some chrome extension?

Comment: Thanks @FedericoMoretti for a response, pushed me to investigate the issue with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue. Putting it here for future reference.

I was using a chrome extension called [Markdown viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk?hl=en) and enabling it causes lot of javascript errors while rendering markdown files on github.